# How do I create a series of high- and low-pitch beeps using Ruby or Python?

Tags: python, ruby

I want to create a series of a low- and high-pitch beeps at fixed times. For example:

- High-pitch beep at 150 ms
- Low-pitch beep at 151 ms
- Low-pitch beep at 200 ms
- High-pitch beep at 250 ms

Is there a way to do this in Ruby or Python? I don't really care what the output encoding is (.wav, .mp3, .ogg, whatever), but I do want to create an output file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a function in Python that makes a file with a single sine wave:

```
# based on : www.daniweb.com/code/snippet263775.html
import math
import wave
import struct

def make_sine(freq=440, datasize=10000, fname="test.wav", framerate=44100.00):
    amp=8000.0 # amplitude
    sine_list=[]
    for x in range(datasize):
        sine_list.append(math.sin(2*math.pi * freq * ( x/frate)))
    # Open up a wav file
    wav_file=wave.open(fname,"w")
    # wav params
    nchannels = 1
    sampwidth = 2
    framerate = int(frate)
    nframes=datasize
    comptype= "NONE"
    compname= "not compressed"
    wav_file.setparams((nchannels, sampwidth, framerate, nframes, comptype, compname))
    #write on file
    for s in sine_list:
        wav_file.writeframes(struct.pack('h', int(s*amp/2)))
    wav_file.close()

frate = 44100.00 #that's the framerate
freq=987.0 #that's the frequency, in hertz
seconds = 3 #seconds of file
data_length = frate*seconds #number of frames
fname = "WaveTest2.wav" #name of file
make_sine(freq, data_length, fname)
```

Not the fastest code...But if you don't need speed, it will work fine!

Comment: The `data_length` variable should be an `int`, so this is more correct: `data_length = int(frate*seconds) #number of frames`, as `range(datasize)` expects `datasize` to be an integer.

Answer (score 2):

Try out the [Ruby Audio File Library](http://cohenaudio.wordpress.com/2010/01/17/rafl-ruby-audio-file-library/) (RAFL). It supports:

> When writing a WAV file:
>
> Write any number of channels at any sample rate
>   Generate white noise, pink noise and sine waves at any amplitude or frequency

Here's the [GitHub source](https://github.com/cohena/RAFL) for the project.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some help for Ruby: [Adding Sound to Your Ruby Apps](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/2007/05/adding-sound-to-your-ruby-apps.html). For actually recording a beep from the pc's speaker to a wav/mp3 -- I don't know if that's possible.

For a beep from your sound card (not speaker), in case you ever need that, simply use the Win32API module that comes with Ruby :

```
require 'Win32API'
Beep = Win32API.new('kernel32', 'Beep', ['I', 'I'], 'I')
Beep.call(1200,150)
Beep.call(200,150)
Beep.call(300,150)
Beep.call(1400,150)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python:

Looks like you need the [winsound](http://docs.python.org/library/winsound.html) module.

Specifically, the function:

```
winsound.Beep(frequency, duration)
```

Which does what you want. But this is specific to Windows only.

There is a package called [beep](http://screenshots.debian.net/package/beep) that allows you to do the same on Linux. So call `beep` using `subprocess` in case you want to have a Linux based solution to this.

Comment: It looks like this causes a beep to happen, but does not match grautur's request for _"I do want to create an output file"_, correct?

Comment: @Phrogz: I did realize this later and was going to delete it but the answer did solve his problem of generating the beeps quite aptly so I decided to let it stay.

Comment: it answers the question as posed in the title so it's half right. Might be useful to some random Googler some day.

Answer (score 0):

For windows users: use the gem win32-sound

```
# gem install win32-sound

require 'win32/sound'
include Win32

Sound.play("SystemAsterisk", Sound::ALIAS) # play system asterisk sound
Sound.beep(600,200) # play a beep 600 hertz for 200 milliseconds
Sound.play("trompet.wav") # play a file from disk
```