# python - how can I generate a WAV file with beeps?

Tags: python, audio, wav

is there a way in python to generate a continuous series of beeps in increasing amplitude and export it into a WAV file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I create a series of high- and low-pitch beeps using Ruby or Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201852/how-do-i-create-a-series-of-high-and-low-pitch-beeps-using-ruby-or-python)

Comment: I looked at the answer there and I can't find a way of changing the volume of the sound

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've based this on the answer to the previous question and added a lot of comments.  Hopefully this makes it clear.  You'll probably want to introduce a for loop to control the number of beeps and the increasing volume.

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
# based on : www.daniweb.com/code/snippet263775.html
import math
import wave
import struct

# Audio will contain a long list of samples (i.e. floating point numbers describing the
# waveform).  If you were working with a very long sound you'd want to stream this to
# disk instead of buffering it all in memory list this.  But most sounds will fit in 
# memory.
audio = []
sample_rate = 44100.0


def append_silence(duration_milliseconds=500):
    """
    Adding silence is easy - we add zeros to the end of our array
    """
    num_samples = duration_milliseconds * (sample_rate / 1000.0)

    for x in range(int(num_samples)): 
        audio.append(0.0)

    return


def append_sinewave(
        freq=440.0, 
        duration_milliseconds=500, 
        volume=1.0):
    """
    The sine wave generated here is the standard beep.  If you want something
    more aggresive you could try a square or saw tooth waveform.   Though there
    are some rather complicated issues with making high quality square and
    sawtooth waves... which we won't address here :) 
    """ 

    global audio # using global variables isn't cool.

    num_samples = duration_milliseconds * (sample_rate / 1000.0)

    for x in range(int(num_samples)):
        audio.append(volume * math.sin(2 * math.pi * freq * ( x / sample_rate )))

    return


def save_wav(file_name):
    # Open up a wav file
    wav_file=wave.open(file_name,"w")

    # wav params
    nchannels = 1

    sampwidth = 2

    # 44100 is the industry standard sample rate - CD quality.  If you need to
    # save on file size you can adjust it downwards. The stanard for low quality
    # is 8000 or 8kHz.
    nframes = len(audio)
    comptype = "NONE"
    compname = "not compressed"
    wav_file.setparams((nchannels, sampwidth, sample_rate, nframes, comptype, compname))

    # WAV files here are using short, 16 bit, signed integers for the 
    # sample size.  So we multiply the floating point data we have by 32767, the
    # maximum value for a short integer.  NOTE: It is theortically possible to
    # use the floating point -1.0 to 1.0 data directly in a WAV file but not
    # obvious how to do that using the wave module in python.
    for sample in audio:
        wav_file.writeframes(struct.pack('h', int( sample * 32767.0 )))

    wav_file.close()

    return


append_sinewave(volume=0.25)
append_silence()
append_sinewave(volume=0.5)
append_silence()
append_sinewave()
save_wav("output.wav")
```

Comment: This program seems to take a lot of time even for creating wav file with 5 beeps (~3 seconds). Is there version of this code using numpy arrays.

Comment: @srinivasuu perhaps this can help: https://soledadpenades.com/posts/2009/fastest-way-to-generate-wav-files-in-python-using-the-wave-module/

Answer (score 3):

I adjusted it a bit further, now it should be a lot faster, and I added a function for playing multiple tones at the same time.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.io.wavfile


class BeepGenerator:
    def __init__(self):
        # Audio will contain a long list of samples (i.e. floating point numbers describing the
        # waveform).  If you were working with a very long sound you'd want to stream this to
        # disk instead of buffering it all in memory list this.  But most sounds will fit in 
        # memory.
        self.audio = []
        self.sample_rate = 44100.0

    def append_silence(self, duration_milliseconds=500):
        """
        Adding silence is easy - we add zeros to the end of our array
        """
        num_samples = duration_milliseconds * (self.sample_rate / 1000.0)

        for x in range(int(num_samples)):
            self.audio.append(0.0)

        return

    def append_sinewave(
            self,
            freq=440.0,
            duration_milliseconds=500,
            volume=1.0):
        """
        The sine wave generated here is the standard beep.  If you want something
        more aggressive you could try a square or saw tooth waveform.   Though there
        are some rather complicated issues with making high quality square and
        sawtooth waves... which we won't address here :) 
        """

        num_samples = duration_milliseconds * (self.sample_rate / 1000.0)

        x = np.array([i for i in range(int(num_samples))])

        sine_wave = volume * np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * (x / self.sample_rate))

        self.audio.extend(list(sine_wave))
        return

    def append_sinewaves(
            self,
            freqs=[440.0],
            duration_milliseconds=500,
            volumes=[1.0]):
        """
        The sine wave generated here is the standard beep.  If you want something
        more aggressive you could try a square or saw tooth waveform.   Though there
        are some rather complicated issues with making high quality square and
        sawtooth waves... which we won't address here :)
        len(freqs) must be the same as len(volumes)
        """

        volumes = list(np.array(volumes)/sum(volumes))
        num_samples = duration_milliseconds * (self.sample_rate / 1000.0)
        x = np.array([i for i in range(int(num_samples))])

        first_it = True
        for volume, freq in zip(volumes, freqs):
            print(freq)
            if first_it:
                sine_wave = volume * np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * (x / self.sample_rate))
                first_it = False
            else:
                sine_wave += volume * np.sin(2 * np.pi * freq * (x / self.sample_rate))

        self.audio.extend(list(sine_wave))
        return

    def save_wav(self, file_name):
        # Open up a wav file
        # wav params

        # 44100 is the industry standard sample rate - CD quality.  If you need to
        # save on file size you can adjust it downwards. The standard for low quality
        # is 8000 or 8kHz.

        # WAV files here are using short, 16 bit, signed integers for the 
        # sample size.  So we multiply the floating point data we have by 32767, the
        # maximum value for a short integer.  NOTE: It is theoretically possible to
        # use the floating point -1.0 to 1.0 data directly in a WAV file but not
        # obvious how to do that using the wave module in python.
        self.audio = np.array(self.audio).astype(np.float32)
        scipy.io.wavfile.write(file_name, int(self.sample_rate), np.array(self.audio))

        return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bg = BeepGenerator()
    bg.append_sinewave(volume=1, duration_milliseconds=100)
    bg.append_silence()
    bg.append_sinewave(volume=0.5, duration_milliseconds=700)
    bg.append_silence()
    bg.append_sinewaves(volumes=[1, 1], duration_milliseconds=700, freqs=[880, 660])
    bg.append_silence()
    bg.save_wav("output.wav")
```

Answer (score 2):

I added minor improvements to the [JCx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3818191/jcx) code above. As author said, its not cool to use global variables. So I wrapped his solution into class, and it works just fine:

```
import math
import wave
import struct

class BeepGenerator:
    def __init__(self):
        # Audio will contain a long list of samples (i.e. floating point numbers describing the
        # waveform).  If you were working with a very long sound you'd want to stream this to
        # disk instead of buffering it all in memory list this.  But most sounds will fit in 
        # memory.
        self.audio = []
        self.sample_rate = 44100.0

    def append_silence(self, duration_milliseconds=500):
        """
        Adding silence is easy - we add zeros to the end of our array
        """
        num_samples = duration_milliseconds * (self.sample_rate / 1000.0)

        for x in range(int(num_samples)): 
            self.audio.append(0.0)

        return    
        
    def append_sinewave(
        self,
        freq=440.0, 
        duration_milliseconds=500, 
        volume=1.0):
        """
        The sine wave generated here is the standard beep.  If you want something
        more aggresive you could try a square or saw tooth waveform.   Though there
        are some rather complicated issues with making high quality square and
        sawtooth waves... which we won't address here :) 
        """ 

        num_samples = duration_milliseconds * (self.sample_rate / 1000.0)

        for x in range(int(num_samples)):
            self.audio.append(volume * math.sin(2 * math.pi * freq * ( x / self.sample_rate )))

        return

    def save_wav(self, file_name):
        # Open up a wav file
        wav_file=wave.open(file_name,"w")

        # wav params
        nchannels = 1

        sampwidth = 2

        # 44100 is the industry standard sample rate - CD quality.  If you need to
        # save on file size you can adjust it downwards. The stanard for low quality
        # is 8000 or 8kHz.
        nframes = len(self.audio)
        comptype = "NONE"
        compname = "not compressed"
        wav_file.setparams((nchannels, sampwidth, self.sample_rate, nframes, comptype, compname))

        # WAV files here are using short, 16 bit, signed integers for the 
        # sample size.  So we multiply the floating point data we have by 32767, the
        # maximum value for a short integer.  NOTE: It is theortically possible to
        # use the floating point -1.0 to 1.0 data directly in a WAV file but not
        # obvious how to do that using the wave module in python.
        for sample in self.audio:
            wav_file.writeframes(struct.pack('h', int( sample * 32767.0 )))

        wav_file.close()

        return    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    bg = BeepGenerator()
    bg.append_sinewave(volume=0.25, duration_milliseconds=100)
    bg.append_silence()
    bg.append_sinewave(volume=0.5, duration_milliseconds=700)
    bg.append_silence()
    bg.save_wav("output.wav")
```